# POST method in CURL not working - getting bad range specification

Tags: curl

I am facing issue in passing the POST request in curl.
I am trying in windows machine.

below is the one which I have tried

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{\"city\":\"Round Rock\",\"state\":\"TX\",\"zipCode\":\"78682\",\"countryCode\":\"CA\",\"orderAmount\":1030.00,\"currencyCode\":\"CAD\",\"cartItems\":[{\"catalogId\": 6007,\"catalogCode\":\"BreakPoint Book\",\"itemNetAmount\": 1000000.0,\"priceIdentifier\":\"5949\"}]}'http://localhost:8080/cart-service/user/18866891/calculate_items_tax
```

I am getting the below exception.

[image]

Can I know how I can change the same request in linux machine as well

Comment: Maybe you miss the whitespace between the body and the URL.

Comment: Also why do you escape the double quotes? That shouldn't be necessary, given that it's enclosed in single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Working one

```
curl -H 'Content-Type:application/json' -d '{"city":"Round Rock","state":"TX","zipCode":"78682","countryCode":"CA","orderAmount":1030.00,"currencyCode":"CAD","cartItems":[{"catalogId": 6007,"catalogCode":"BreakPoint Book","itemNetAmount": 1000000.0,"priceIdentifier":"5949"}]}'  http://localhost:8080/cart-service/user/18866891/calculate_items_tax
```